# Check if one element equal the previous element R

Tags: r, loops, vector, vectorization

I'm trying to make a logic vector to check if one element is equal to previous element.

```
vector <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

I'd like to check each element if it's equal to the previous, therefore the resuld should be:

```
   FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

I know I could make a loop, buts it's not efficient (i have a 16 million row df).
So

it's not the ideal, but is what I could manage:

```
for(i in 2:length(vector)) {print(vector[i] == vector[i-1])}
```

that would take forever. Is there any vectorized way to do that?

Comment: or `c(FALSE, head(vector, -1) == tail(vector, -1))`

Comment: You can also: `c(FALSE,vector[-1]==vector[-length(vector)])`.

Comment: that works, just need one adaptation `c(FALSE, !diff(x) >0)` or it returno the contrary.
Any idea how to do that for character vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` answer. Note that the first item is really an NA. You can manually edit that one if desired.

```
library("data.table")
vector <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)

df <- data.frame(original=vector)
setDT(df)
df[, prev_eq := original==shift(vector,1)]
```

Answer (score 7):

We can use (better for integer vector)

```
c(FALSE, diff(x) == 0)
```

**Example**

```
x <- c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)

c(FALSE, diff(x) == 0)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

If your vector contains floating point numbers, this is more robust:

```
c(FALSE, abs(diff(x)) < .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5)
```

but it will costs three times more memory and possibly three times slower than the above for really huge vector.

---

If you have character vector, we can use

```
c(FALSE, x[-1] == x[-length(x)])
```

It is always safe to compare strings using `"=="`.